# Filter postgresql query if multiple rows exist

Tags: postgresql

right now I have the following table:

```
students      |       classes       | 
-------------------------------------
Ally          |       Math          |        
Ally          |       English       |        
Ally          |       Science       |       
Kim           |       Math          |        
Kim           |       English       |
```

I am currently building an advanced search feature where you can search by class and return students who have those classes. I would like to build a query that will return student's that have Math and English and Science in the classes column, so in the case above it would only return the rows that have Ally in them, since she meets the three classes criteria.

If anyone has any advice I would greatly appriciate it, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've renamed your tables and such slightly, but partly cause I'm lazy.  Here's what I came up with:

```
select student from studentclasses where
  class in ('Math', 'English', 'Science')
group by student
having count(*) = 3;
```

See the [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rM3KDAVSjVRgmFZD8nRQPj/0)

The idea is to grab all the student-class rows that match what your search is (basically an OR) and group it by the student so that we can limit by the having clause.  We could use `>=` here, but if count for a particular student gets more than 3, we screwed up the IN :)  If there are fewer than 3, then we're missing one class, so not all classes were found for that student.

The only caveats are:

- I'm assuming you're using a student ID rather than just first name, and that the first name bit is just to make it easier for us to read, otherwise duplicates will abound.
- There are no duplicates of a given class for a particular student. That is, if Kim is in Science twice, then that comes up with 3. In that case, you'll need to use a DISTINCT in there somewhere.

Comment: This is an elegant solution! I was going to propose running explicit subqueries for each class, and then rejoining them to the full table, but this does all of that in 40 less lines.

Comment: Thanks Tanktalus!  And you correct that there will be a unique id as well as one 1 entry per class, Thanks again!